# Question: MT8888 How are ‘Register’s setup; Read Status Register and Write to Control Register?

Tags: pins

I’m using PIC18F2520 and MT8888C. The “Data Sheet” I’m using is Zarlink Sem. “Integrated DTMF Transceiver, with Intel Micro Interface”.

I’m looking at page Figure 16, “Test Circuits”, the first test I tried was “INITIALIZATION PROCEDURE”. The tests were several, it didn’t work.

Question: MT8888 How are ‘Register’s setup; Read Status Register and Write to Control Register?

I couldn’t see how the ‘Register’s setup control from the PIC. If MT8888C pins could be put with the PIC18F2520 pins like USART or other pins.

Comment: Maybe [edit] and include a link or a screeshot of the page in your question

Comment: Describe how exactly the tests were done ... since the "reset".

Answer (score 0):

> Question: MT8888 How are ‘Register’s setup; Read Status Register and Write to Control Register?

The MT8888 is controlled by four control lines, four data lines, and signals the microcontroller over an interrupt line, making nine total connections. This is not a UART connection, but a chip-specific protocol that you will need to carefully bit-bang over GPIO. The test procedure described in figure 17 requires you to drive (and/or sample as inputs) eight different communication lines while meeting the timing constraints on page 21.

The 8888 is designed to operate with specific Intel processors that can natively handle this timing and are designed with a data bus for IO. Emulating this functionality on a general-purpose microcontroller is certainly possible, but very difficult to do properly, fraught with pitfalls, and well beyond the scope of an answer here. If you really do need to use this tone generator, the best option is to get an 8051 or 8085 and use it instead of the PIC.